# Java app always deployed as a new App Service on Azure

Tags: java, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to deploy .jar SpringBoot app via Azure Shell. I already have created (via site) the App Service Plan & App Service so in the pom config I mention the names of existing service. So when I'm trying to run `mvn azure-webapp:deploy` it always fails with

> "Service with this name already exist"

Is there a way to force using existing AppService without creating a new one? Because now it looks like it's going to try creating with every update I make.

Upd: My **working** plugin setup

```
             <plugin>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-webapp-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.12.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaVersion>V2</schemaVersion>
                    <resourceGroup>___</resourceGroup>
                    <appName>___</appName>
                    <appServicePlanName>___</appServicePlanName>
                    <pricingTier>F1</pricingTier>
                    <region>eastus</region>
                    <runtime>
                        <os>windows</os>
                        <javaVersion>11</javaVersion>
                        <webContainer>java 11</webContainer>
                    </runtime>
                    <!-- Begin of App Settings  -->
                    <appSettings>
                        <property>
                            <name>JAVA_OPTS</name>
                            <value>-Dserver.port=80 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true</value>
                        </property>
                    </appSettings>
                    <!-- End of App Settings  -->
                    <deployment>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>*.jar</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </deployment>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/issues/927) they recommend downgrading to older version (1.6.0) and it has worked for me but I'd prefer some better solution.

Answer (score 1):

**The Java Jdk version is the problem.**

---

I have an exist azure app service, and an empty spring boot application works well locally, which downloads from here: `git clone https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-spring-boot`

[image]

Here is the **pom.xml** deploying to exist app service works well on my side.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">  
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>  
  <parent> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>  
    <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>  
    <relativePath/>  
    <!-- lookup parent from repository --> 
  </parent>  
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>  
  <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>  
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>  
  <name>spring-boot</name>  
  <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>  
  <properties> 
    <java.version>1.8</java.version> 
  </properties>  
  <dependencies> 
    <dependency> 
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId> 
    </dependency>  
    <!-- tag::actuator[] -->  
    <dependency> 
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId> 
    </dependency>  
    <!-- end::actuator[] -->  
    <!-- tag::tests[] -->  
    <dependency> 
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>  
      <scope>test</scope>  
      <exclusions> 
        <exclusion> 
          <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>  
          <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId> 
        </exclusion> 
      </exclusions> 
    </dependency>  
    <!-- end::tests[] --> 
  </dependencies>  
  <build> 
    <plugins> 
      <plugin> 
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
      </plugin>  
      <plugin> 
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>  
        <artifactId>azure-webapp-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
        <version>1.12.0</version>  
        <configuration> 
          <schemaVersion>v2</schemaVersion>  
          <subscriptionId>xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx</subscriptionId>  
          <resourceGroup>MyRG</resourceGroup>  
          <appName>dorisspring</appName>  
          <pricingTier>B1</pricingTier>  
          <region>centralus</region>  
          <runtime> 
            <os>Windows</os>  
            <javaVersion>Java 8</javaVersion>  
            <webContainer>Java SE</webContainer> 
          </runtime>  
          <deployment> 
            <resources> 
              <resource> 
                <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>  
                <includes> 
                  <include>*.jar</include> 
                </includes> 
              </resource> 
            </resources> 
          </deployment> 
        </configuration> 
      </plugin> 
    </plugins> 
  </build> 
</project>
```

**Here is my commands:**

```
mvn spring-boot:run
mvn clean install #check the "target" folder including jdk created by this command
mvn azure-webapp:config
mvn azure-webapp:deploy
```

**Deploy succeeded:**

[image]

**Tips: make sure the java version match.**

Comment: Thanks! In my case java is 11 and I tried doing my thing with azure plugin 1.12.0 and it went good in the end

Comment: Glad to help. Would you mind accept as the answer for others to refer? @Mary

Answer (score -1):

What has worked in the end for my setup (see edited question for plugin config) is to use the latest version of azure plugin (1.12.0). It seems like the problem is fixed there. Otherwise try to use an older version (e.g. it worked for me with 1.6.0 see comment under question)